# How to setState by value in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there a simpler way to update state if I have the name of the attribute? Something simpler than this:

```
function thingChanged(name, value) { 
  var x = {};
  x[name] = value;
  this.setState(x)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to further reduce the code with the current ECMAScript version. Perhaps with ES6 it might be possible, depending on what features will the language have.

However if you're worried about code redundancy, you can add that method to a mixing and refer it in all components that you need to.

**Update:** Thanks to @FakeRainBrigand for providing the ES6 syntax that allows the code reduction: `setState({[name]: value});`

Comment: That would actually change state key called `name` to value, not a key based on variable `name`. Therefore it differs from the original question.

Comment: As zvona said, that's incorrect. The fact that that syntax doesn't work is the reason for my question.

Comment: Argh, you're right, I don't know how I missed the indexed usage of the property. In this case there's no alternative to reduce that code (at least no in ES5). However if you're worried about code redundancy you can use mixins that define the `thingChanged` method.

Comment: I will update my answer an remove the incorrect code (hopefully it didn't affected too many people :)

Comment: In ES6 `setState({[name]: value})` is valid. For me it's still 3 lines (it's difficult to make out with three different opening brackets together for me) so there's little difference.  It is useful with something like the updates addon, though for deeper changes.

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand thanks for the tip, is it ok if I quote you in my answer?

Answer (score 2):

It’s not exactly shorter but this should work:

```
function thingChanged(name, value) { 
  this.setState(Object.defineProperty({}, name, {value:value}))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

ES6 shorthands:

`this.setState({...x});`

`this.setState({ x });`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the `thingChanged` function for two-way data binding the [LinkedStateMixin](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/two-way-binding-helpers.html) will help you do it with less code.